# Proof the Presence of a Constant (Either $1$ or $-1$) in Chebyshev Polynomials of the First Kind ($T_n$) for Even Values of $n$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing

The Chebyshev Polynomials of the first kind are given as follows:

\begin{align*}
T_0(x) & = \mathbf{1} \\
T_1(x) & = x \\
T_2(x) & = 2x^2 - \mathbf{1} \\
T_3(x) & = 4x^3 - 3x \\
T_4(x) & = 8x^4 - 8x^2 + \mathbf{1} \\
T_5(x) & = 16x^5 - 20x^3 + 5x \\
T_6(x) & = 32x^6 - 48x^4 + 18x^2 - \mathbf{1} \\
T_7(x) & = 64x^7 - 112x^5 + 56x^3 - 7x \\
T_8(x) & = 128x^8 - 256x^6 + 160x^4 - 32x^2 + \mathbf{1} \\
T_9(x) & = 256x^9 - 576x^7 + 432x^5 -120x^3 +9x \\
T_{10}(x) & = 512x^{10} -1280x^{8} +1120x^{6} -400x^{4} +50x^{2} -\mathbf{1}
\end{align*}

It is observed that when $n$ in $T_{n}$ is an even number, the polynomial includes a constant term, which is either $\mathbf{1}$ or $\mathbf{-1}$, depending on whether $n/2$ is odd or even. How can we mathematically prove the aforementioned observation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They verify for all $x$, $T_n(\cos(x)) = \cos(nx)$ thus the constant terms are $T_n(0) = T_n(\cos(\pi/2)) = \cos(n\pi/2)$, which equals $0$, $1$ or $-1$ in function of the remainder of $n$ modulo $4$.